# How to customise the border color of tkinter/ttk widgets and frames?

Tags: python, windows, colors, tkinter, border

Is there any way to customize the border color of a `Tkinter/ttk` widgets or frames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own *style* and apply it to the widget or configure the attributes of an existing style.

Some documentation and examples are in the official docs, specifically the section about [ttk.Style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html?highlight=ttk%20style#tkinter.ttk.Style).

Additional information on using styles (for several languages) can be found at [tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html).

Comment: I can see many ways to change the properties of a widget, but none of them refer to a widget's border color. I'm wondering if you're thinking of a specific Tcl/Tix feature that isn't supported by the Python Tkinter/ttk wrappers?

Comment: @Malcolm: I think the whole tcl/tk/ttk interface is exposed to Tkinter. Unfortunately, showing how to configure a style can't be done in just a couple lines of code, it's a bit too complex for that. For inspiration, however, take a look at this code which shows how to create a frame with rounded corners: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Demo/tkinter/ttk/roundframe.py. You'll need to tweak the imports if you want to run it with python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you! Your demo really opened my eyes as to the power of TKinter/ttk. For those following this thread, here are the changes required to run Bryan's example with Python 2.7 - change the first 2 import statements to this: import Tkinter as tkinter; import ttk

Comment: @Malcolm: there are probably very few people who realize just how powerful tk is, especially with the themed widgets. Unfortunately there's not a lot of documentation for doing such creative things as rounded corners with custom highlights based on widget state, but it's possible. You can certainly make a Tkinter based app that *nobody* would know was based on Tkinter if you put a little effort into it. Pundits would be very surprised.

Comment: I'm blown away by the power that's hidden beneath the surface of Tkinter. Quote: "You can certainly make a Tkinter based app that nobody would know was based on Tkinter if you put a little effort into it." ... I agree. And that's exactly what we're trying to do :) Thank you for all your help!

Comment: First link is dead. Is it this one: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html?highlight=ttk%20style#tkinter.ttk.Style

Comment: @Plasma: I've fixed the link. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: @BryanOakley http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Demo/tkinter/ttk/roundframe.py this link shows **Not Found**. Can you please give the link of styles for the frame with rounded corner.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a border on ttk.Frames: in lieu of styles, the best I can think of is to insert a ttk.Frame within a ttk.Frame. The outer frame would use a standard "background" property with the border color of choice, and a padding equal to the desired border thickness. The inner frame then obscures the middle, so you have a line only around the edges. Works, but seems a little bit hacky (and a bit less wieldy if you're creating many widgets/borders).

I've searched quite a bit and haven't found or figured out a way to use a style to change a ttk.Frame's border color. Using something like `style.configure( 'SeletectedItem.TFrame', highlightcolor='#78F', highlightthickness=2 )` or `style.configure( 'SeletectedItem.TFrame', highlightbackground='#78F', highlightcolor='#78F', highlightthickness=2, borderwidth=2 )` (config options that work on a regular Tk.Frame) doesn't seem to do anything. With `style.layout()` I find just `[('Frame.border', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]`, and from `style.element_options('TFrame.border'`) there is just `('-relief',)`. I don't know if I'm using the wrong option names or syntax (or what options are available for `.configure()` for different widget classes), or if this just isn't possible with styles. I'm interested if anyone has extra info or knows if this can be done.